# How to migrate AS2 to AS3.?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How to convert ActionScript 2.0 code to ActionScript 3.0

this is code :

```
    //***********************************************************
    var theXML:XML = new XML();
    theXML.ignoreWhite = true;
    theXML.onLoad = function() {
    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    theList.addItem(nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue,i);
    }
    }

    theXML.load("http://localhost/conn.php");
    //***********************************************************
```

This is my PHP code that **echo**'s an XML string :

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
echo "<name>\n"; 

while ( $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) 
{ echo "<item>" . $line["name"] . "</item>\n"; } 

echo "</name>\n"
```

Using AS3, how do I parse the XML string as actual XML data with nodes?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your AS3 attempt code and someone will try fix it for you... Are you trying to loading an XML file or a PHP file (or PHP echos an XML data)??? Whatever case, it's all in the **AS3 API** manual. Google it.

Comment: i have trouble to display  PHP echos an XML data into flash can u help me please this is code from php : echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
echo "<name>\n";
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo "<item>" . $line["name"] . "</item>\n";
}
echo "</name>\n"

Comment: google it before ask a question, like this "load xml data using actionscript 3"

Comment: So your real question is **how to load XML data in AS3**, right? That's the tutorial you should've google'd. Anyways you have a correct answer below. If it works then "mark as correct" to finalise the question.

Comment: thank you #VC.One for help :)

Comment: i'm new here sorry I see it, and do it thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples of [how to work with XML in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html), and [how to migrate AS2 to AS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_3).

This would be the equivalent of what you posted:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/conn.php"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

function loaderComplete(e:Event):void {
    XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
    var xml:XML = new XML(loader.data);
    var nodes:XMLList = xml.child(0).children();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
        theList.addItem(nodes[i].child(0).text());
    }
}
```

Note that in AS3 you can reference XML nodes by name, for example `xml.gallery.image[3].url` instead of `xml.child(0).children()[3].child(0)`, etc.